# Java - read text file starting from second line

Tags: java, csv, io

I am trying to read a txt file in java. However, I only want to read starting from the second line since the first line is just a label. This is the example

Text File:

```
Name,Type,Price
Apple,Fruit,3
Orange,Fruit,2
Lettuce,Veggie,1
```

How do I do this? I have this code where you can read from first line.

Code:

```
//read the file, line by line from txt
File file = new File("train/traindata.txt");
FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
String line;

line = br.readLine();

while(line != null)
{
    lines = line.split(",");

    //Do something for line here
    //Store the data read into a variable

    line = br.readLine();         
}

fr.close();
```

Please help me, Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just add an extra `BufferedReader#readLine` call...

```
br.readLine(); // consume first line and ignore
line = br.readLine();
while(line != null) ...
```

Comment: This answer is a testament to "don't make it harder than it has to be" :-)

Comment: @Gikkman But it is *also* a good example how not-very-robust code can come into existence.

Comment: @GhostCat You have a very good point. Depending on the required robustness and longevity of the project, the simple solution is not always the correct one

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it was the requirement for the text file haha

Answer (score 3):

In case you are interested in using a third party library, here is an example using [Apache Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) (it will skip the header, but keep its mapping for retrieval of fields from the record).

Modify the charset according to your file's encoding.

```
   CSVParser parser = CSVParser.parse(file, Charset.forName("UTF-8"),CSVFormat.RFC4180.withFirstRecordAsHeader().withSkipHeaderRecord());

   List<CSVRecord> records = parser.getRecords();

   for (CSVRecord record : records) {

       System.out.println(record.get("Name"));
       System.out.println(record.get("Type"));
       System.out.println(record.get("Price"));
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do the following in while condition:

```
line = br.readLine();

while((line=br.readLine()) != null)
{
    lines = line.split(",");

    //Do something for line here
    //Store the data read into a variable

    line = br.readLine();         
}

fr.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are converting  txt file into CSV Parser

So I suggest you..

```
br.readLine(); // Header of CSV
line = br.readLine();
while(line != null)
{
 // Your Logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just read and skip the first line

```
//read the file, line by line from txt
File file = new File("train/traindata.txt");
FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
String line;

line = br.readLine();
boolean first = true;
while(line != null)
{
    if (first) {
      first = false;
    } else {
      lines = line.split(",");

      //Do something for line here
      //Store the data read into a variable

      line = br.readLine();         
    }
}

fr.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose a somehow different solution: ignoring lines without having a look into them ... of course works; but that approach is not very robust upon changes to your file content!

What happens if you change your files to have

```
header

data
```

or

```
data
data
```

So, my suggestion goes like this --- keep your current code, but ensure that you only pick lines with *valid* data; for example by reworking your loop body:

```
lines = line.split(",");
if (lines.length == 3 && isNumber(lines[2])) ...
```

where *isNumber()* is a little helper function that checks if the incoming string is well, a number.

In other words: skipping lines intentionally implicitly **hard codes** knowledge about the file layout into your "parser". That might be OK for simple exercises, but in the *real world* such things **will** break at some point in the future. And then the fun begins. Because **nobody** will remember that the parsing code is written to throw away the first line of the file.

And as shown, you can easily avoid that kind of problem!