# How To Read Second Line In Text With Java

Tags: java, parsing, url, methods, text-files

I am trying to create a simple command line program that will determine if a playlist is a media playlist or master based on the tag returned. Unfortunately both type of playlist first line tags are the same so I was wondering is their a way I could adjust my code to read the text starting at the second line?

```html
private static String getPlaylistUrl(String theUrl) throws 
 FileNotFoundException, MalformedURLException, IOException{
  String content = "";
   //Creates a url variable 
   URL url = new URL(theUrl);
   //Cretes a urlConnection variable 
   URLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
   //Wraps the urlConnection in a BufferedReader 
   BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
   String line;
   
   while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    content += line + "\n";
   }
   bufferedReader.close();
 
  
 
  return content;
  
 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - read text file starting from second line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40134193/java-read-text-file-starting-from-second-line)

Answer (score 2):

Just read the first line before the loop starts.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static String getPlaylistUrl(String theUrl) throws IOException {
    try (InputStream is = new URL(theUrl).openConnection().getInputStream();
         BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
         Stream<String> stream = reader.lines()) {
        return stream
                // skip the first line
                .skip(1)
                // join all other lines using a new line delimiter
                .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Skip the header like this

```
String line;
bool IsHeader=true;

        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        if (IsHeader){
            IsHeader=false; //skip header..

        }else{
        content += line + "\n";
        }

        }
        bufferedReader.close();
```